# Sorting mysql by number of occurrences

Tags: mysql, sorting

How do you order a mysql table by the number of occurrences in a spesific column?

Example table:

```
ID Name
1  Alfred
2  Alfred
3  Burt
4  Alfred
5  Jill
6  Jill
7  Jill
8  Jill
9  Burt
```

The sorted table should be like below, since "Jill" is the name occurring most, it should be sorted first, and so on:

```
ID Name
5  Jill
6  Jill
7  Jill
8  Jill
1  Alfred
2  Alfred
4  Alfred
3  Burt
9  Burt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to bring in the information into the query.  This is typically done using a `join`:

```
select e.*
from example e join
     (select name, count(*) as cnt
      from example
      group by name
     ) en
     on e.name = en.name
order by cnt desc, e.name, e.id;
```

Note that the `order by` not only orders by the count.  It also orders by the name.  If two names have the same count, then it will keep them together.

Comment: The example resultset also appears to be ordered by `id` (It's not stated that this is a requirement, but adding `e.id` to the `ORDER BY` would make the result more deterministic. My preference is tp qualify _all_ column references, `ORDER BY en.cnt, e.name, e.id`, to avoid a problem (later) e.g. if someone later adds a column named `cnt` to the `example` table. (Qualifying all column references is a best practice.)